# PHP - How to position in one array

Tags: php, arrays

How to position in one array thanks to one keys known, and to put in a variable all the keys which follow, the first key included ?

*My key known :* "`r`"

*The key stop :* "`s`"

*My array :*

```
['a'] => US
['r'] => UK
['v'] => DE
['s'] => IR     
['k'] => IT    
['o'] => AS
```

*Result* = r v

Comment: Your array is invalid. You can't have the 'r' index twice.

Answer (score 2):

suppose you s key is behind r, here is the code:

**[Demo here](https://eval.in/708630)**

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$flip_keys = array_flip($keys);
$result = array_slice($keys, $flip_keys['r'], $flip_keys['s'] - $flip_keys['r']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the full array and check keys are inside the required bounds:

```
foreach( $theArray as $key => $value )
{
    if( $key >= 'r' && $key < 's' )
    {
        // will enter here with keys 'r' and 'v'

        $theArray[ $key ] = $theNewValue
    }
}
```

This assuming you want to catch all the values with keys that are **alphabetically** between "r" and "s" ("s" excluded).

This is not completely clear from your question.

**Instead** if you want to catch the values between "r" and "s" according to the array order then the codes changes slightly:

```
$update = false
foreach( $theArray as $key => $value )
{
    if( $key == 'r' )
    {
        $update = true;
    }
    elseif( $key == 's' )
    {
        break;
    }

    if( $update )
    {
        // will enter here with keys 'r' and 'v'

        $theArray[ $key ] = $theNewValue
    }
}
```